# Google Spreadsheets: Search strings in multiple rows & return row number if true

Tags: google-sheets

I've been looking on the forums for a while trying to learn google's scripting language to create some shortcuts for me in Google Spreadsheets, but so far nothing is really panning out.

I'm trying to work out how to search whether 2 cells in the same row have a specific string & the other be empty.
(H having the string "Active" & K being empty)
For every Row that this happens, that cell number is returned.

This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(LOOKUP("Active", H1:H) & (LOOKUP(ISBLANK(),K1:K))), CELL(ROW())
```

I'm still fairly new to coding an would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`=ArrayFormula(IF((H:H="Active")*(K:K=""), ROW(H:H), ""))`

paste in the first row.